# 興味が湧く vs 興味が沸く​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Tags: word-choice, usage, words, set-phrases

Which kanji should we use for the *phrase* 興味がわく (to mean that something has caught our interest)?

Some quick googling shows that both 興味が湧く ([~11m hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E8%88%88%E5%91%B3%E3%81%8C%E6%B9%A7%E3%81%8F%22)) and 興味が沸く ([~9m hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E8%88%88%E5%91%B3%E3%81%8C%E6%B2%B8%E3%81%8F%22)) are widely used. Is one of them simply a typo error, or are both of them *correct*?

What is the difference in nuance and usage between 興味が湧く and 興味が沸く?

Comment: [Google counts may not be as reliable as you imagine](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/522/google-counts-may-not-be-as-reliable-as-you-imagine).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which kanji should we use for the phrase 興味がわく

湧く. You should be able to verify this in a dictionary, such as [here](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8F&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=19791000), #4.

> What is the difference in nuance and usage between 興味が湧く and 興味が沸く?

One is spelled correctly while the other is not.